# remove quotes inside quotes regex php

Tags: php, regex, quotes

My String goes like this:

```
[...] 
if(round($pdf->GetY() >= 140)) { 
    $pdf->AddPage(); 
}
$pdf->Write(6,'Dutzler, Herbert - Letzter' Saibling'); 
$pdf->Ln(7); 
$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','B',9); 
$pdf->SetTextColor(3 [...]
```

As you can see, FPDF cannot execute this command:

```
$pdf->Write(6,'Dutzler, Herbert - Letzter' Saibling');
```

because there is a quote inside quotes and it crashes.

Do you have any idea how I can remove or replace those inner quotes using regex? I have tried many different things, seems not to work properly :(

the code is coming from a huge database, here's a peek at the input code:

> [LOOP] $pdf->Write(6,'[title]'); $pdf->Ln(7); 
>   $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','B',9); [LOOP]

str_replace doesn't work properly if there are quotes inside [title] so it already fails at $str='[title]'. It's weird, I know.

Answer (score 3):

Either escape the inside quote:

```
$pdf->Write(6,'Dutzler, Herbert - Letzter\' Saibling');
```

or use double quotes around the string instead of single quotes:

```
$pdf->Write(6,"Dutzler, Herbert - Letzter' Saibling");
```

No need for regexp, just write the code correctly in the first place.

Comment: I can only modify the output of the string, not the input.

Comment: Then I think you're out of luck. How is a program supposed to know which quotes need to be replaced? You can't just look for parentheses, what if the argument to `Write` contains parentheses, too?

Comment: Where is this string coming from? You need to fix that.

Comment: Well I know how the term I am searching for starts and ends: pdf->Write(6,' .... '). So I thought I could do a double preg_replace of some sort where I only kill quotes if they start with pdf write blah and end with ').

Comment: good point, but I think the odds that Write contains parantheses and quotes at the same time are pretty low

Comment: What if it contains `$pdf->Write(6, 'Foo' . 'Bar');`? Those inner quotes shouldn't be replaced? You practically have to write your own PHP parser to do this right.

Comment: Why are you allowing incorrect code into the database in the first place? And why do they expect it to work correctly?

Comment: @Barmar Do you have any relevance to Steve Ballmer?

Comment: @revo The former Microsoft CEO? No, I never met him. Why would I be relevant to him? Because Barmar sounds sort of like Ballmer?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried addslashes()? It should add slashes before quotes.

Comment: addslashes() adds slashes to all quotes of the page, but I only need them inside specific quotes pdf->Write(6," ....... ");

Comment: Addslashes($content) adds slashes only on specified content: pdf->Write(6,addslashes(" ....... "));